# Move version number to a variable in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My `build.gradle.kts` contains my dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.1.6")
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-test:3.1.6")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}
```

How can I move the `3.1.6` to a local variable (?) so I can avoid duplicating it in several places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want it local, you can add a value to your `dependencies` block:

```kt
dependencies {
    val koinVersion = "3.1.6"

    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion")
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koinVersion")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}
```

If you want to use it multiple spots, you can add an `extra` value in your project's `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kt
val koinVersion by extra { "3.1.6" }
```

then in the app's `build.gradle.kts` file, you import it before using it:

```kt
val koinVersion: String by rootProject.extra

dependencies {
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion")
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koinVersion")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
def koinVersion = '3.1.6'
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion"
```